# Jquery AJAX causes SLOW page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a javascript function that looks like this:

```
function getAlerts() {
    $.post('getAlerts.php', function(data) {
        //Do stuff
        setTimeout(getAlerts, 1000);
    });
}
```

I then have in the document.ready block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    setTimeout(getAlerts, 1000);
}
```

I want the getAlerts function to be called every second, starting one second after the page has loaded. However, when I add this callback to the document.ready block, it causes the entire page to load extremely slowly, if at all. What am I missing here?

EDIT: I also notice that the slow page load only starts after enabling the getAlerts function, and refreshing the page a couple times. The first few refreshes seem fine. Is it possibly that the AJAX calls are bottlenecking somewhere?

Comment: I'd wager that it's the `//Do stuff` part.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL What's MDGG BGLL? ;)

Comment: I don't think so, I tried removing everything, and the load still seems very slow.

Comment: Since you are using the complete callback to do the setTimeout, the slowdown either has to be the server taking a long time to respond, or the `//Do stuff` section being slow. This should not affect the page load at all due to the fact that it happens after the page is done loading (other than images)

Comment: Why use setTimeout and not setInterval?

Comment: @MikeFielden setTimeout is better in this case to prevent the ajax requests from backing up when the server that he is requesting from becomes unavailable or slow due to the client's location/network.

Comment: @KevinB Touche... :) Maybe a more robust way is to use deferreds or something similar to achieve this. When "A" is done run the call requesting data from the server again?

Comment: Sorry @user500343 I didnt mean to hijack your question...

Comment: @MikeFielden No problem. Re-requesting data from the server once the ajax call returns is exactly what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try taking out the setTimeout, it's delaying the function by a second. Also you may want to take a look at the php code that you are posting to. If it is making tons of mysql queries or something that could be slowing your load time as well.

Comment: Only making about 5-10 (MAX) SQL queries on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

To any future persons reading this post, the problem was eventually resolved. It ended up being a server-side issue with some old code that I'd forgot about causing a hang. Thanks to everyone that responded.